# ORA-39002, ORA-39070, ORA-29283, ORA-06512 and ORA-29283 when executing a .sh

Tags: oracle, sh, putty, impdp, dmp

I'm trying to import a backup onto another database.

Here's my "`imp_schema.sh`" file:

```
impdp userid=system/admin2018@NODO1 content=data_only full=n schemas=prueba directory=BACKUPS dumpfile=full_import.dmp logfile=prueba.log
```

So, I log in (On the source server) as oracle/oracle and do the following:

```html
$ bash
bash-3.00$ cd /oradata2/backups/
bash-3.00$ ./imp_schema.sh

Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Feb 6 11:10:36 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation


bash-3.00$
```

The .dmp and .sh file are both inside "/oradata2/backups/"

Doing a

`SELECT DIRECTORY_NAME, DIRECTORY_PATH FROM DBA_DIRECTORIES;`

on the Source Directory through SQL shows the directory as:

```
DIRECTORY_NAME  DIRECTORY_PATH
BACKUPS /oradata2/backups
```

Why am I having this error?

Comment: Well, it says it can't open the log file. Probably permission denied. Can you show the output of `ls -l /oradata2/backups/prueba.log`?

Comment: Or try doing `touch /oradata2/backups/prueba.log` and see if it works.

Comment: The "prueba.log" is unexistant. the script's supposed to create it after running.

Comment: may be the user does not have write permissions on the working directory?

Comment: Thanks for the response! How could I check that? I can also log as "Root", but then I can't use bash or run a .sh

Comment: try creating a zero byte file in the directory. eg: `touch filename` . If you find no errors that means you have write permissions. Also check if the oracle osuser has write permissions on the directory. In other words check if all relevant permissions(os/unix/db)  are in place before proceeding.

Comment: Did create a file and removed it.

How'd I check osuser write permissions on the directory?